# Chrome: navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I'm on localhost and trying to use the MediaDevices.getUserMedia method in Chrome. I receive the error as titled. I understand that in Chrome it is only possible to use this function with a secure origin and that localhost is considered a secure origin. Also, this works in Firefox.

This is how I'm using it as shown on the Google Developers website https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices?hl=en:

```
var constraints = window.constraints = {
            audio: false,
            video: true
};


navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
            callFactory.broadcastAssembly(stream);
            ...
});
```

Comment: I think you need to have HTTPS in order to get it to work.

Comment: @Tom Serving over localhost is specifically allowed: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

Comment: @Nateowami not at the time I wrote the comment, though.

Answer (score 10):

On some latest browsers `navigator.getUserMedia` does not perform well. So, try using [navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia). Or, better you check if `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` is available for the browser use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` or else use `navigator.getUserMedia`.

```
navigator.getWebcam = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webKitGetUserMedia || navigator.moxGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);
if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({  audio: true, video: true })
    .then(function (stream) {
                  //Display the video stream in the video object
     })
     .catch(function (e) { logError(e.name + ": " + e.message); });
}
else {
navigator.getWebcam({ audio: true, video: true }, 
     function (stream) {
             //Display the video stream in the video object
     }, 
     function () { logError("Web cam is not accessible."); });
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 8):

Try enabling: chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features

Worked for me in chromium

Comment: Worked for me as well. Is `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` defined in Chrome but not Chromium? MDN [warns against using](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) the deprecated  `navigator.getUserMedia`, warning that "it may break at any time." I'm trying not to use it, but `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` isn't available in Chromium without changing that flag. EDIT: Contrary to what I read, it [didn't come out until Chrome 53](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) (I'm using Chromium 52).

Comment: I found the answer in the footnotes on MDN: `From version 47 to 52, the promise-based interface was only available through the adapter.js polyfill, or using the flag chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features. Starting with version 53, the promise-based interface is on by default, though that interface is still not available through navigator.`

Comment: I'm using Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit), and `#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` has not helped me with using Twilio: https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-js/blob/7f069897320d063fdadb1819a36d8b72b16e4923/public/quickstart.js.

Comment: Darn. I'm back again and didn't read my comment above and tried again in Brave (`Brave is up to date Version 1.22.71 Chromium: 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)`) and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

I too had the same  problem in my chrome browser.
first check your phone is supported by testing it in https://test.webrtc.org/

if your phone passes all the cases, then check step 2

step 2:
If your hosting a webpage or running a third party webpage,see whether camera permissions are enabled on your phone.

Also the main issue is **WEBRTC is not supported in HTTP site and it is supported only in HTTPS site**

[This is the https site which allows web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcJmw.jpg)
 [This is the http site which gives a error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0keA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck in the same issue. One solution is to follow and download the extension [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb) shared in the comment above by @ellerynz, or

if you have python installed you could also do

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer [port]
```

After you hit enter, you should see the following message:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Open the browser and put

```
http://127.0.0.1:[port]
```

Comment: Excellent - ran exactly into this using `SimpleHTTPServer`; changing IP from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1 solved it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include `adapter.js` polyfill ? Check this page : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Browser_compatibility

It looks like this or enabling `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` as per `@Simon Malone`'s note, is needed for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too and changing flags didn't seem to work. I came across this chrome extension — [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb) in Google's [WebRTC tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0) which seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Use [navigator.getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) instead.

```
navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: I was hoping to use MediaDevices.getUserMedia because Navigator.getUserMedia is listed as deprecated on Mozilla. I'm still confused why the former does not work for me.

Comment: You can use the one you want, but you'll have to write some kind of polyfill.