# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: jquery, webrtc, recordrtc

Please help me our as I am new in recordrtc functionality and i am getting this error navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia  'undefined' is not an object and it is not working in safari browser only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assume no one knows anything about what you are talking about. What are trying to do, what did you try, and what results did you get? All of this must be in the body of the question. You need to include code where relevant! Without these details, this question is likely to be removed.

Comment: Related: [Chrome: navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315361/chrome-navigator-mediadevices-getusermedia-is-not-a-function?rq=3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari only supports getUserMedia since version 11 (which has just been released): http://caniuse.com/stream/embed/description

Check for support (i.e. is navigator.mediaDevices a thing) before using it.